# autocomplete with apostrophe does not show result

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following javascript:

```
$('#txtCompanyQuery').autocomplete(
    {
        source: function(request, response) {
            request.term = request.term.replace(/'/gi, "\\'");
        },
        serviceUrl: _handlerUrl + '?step=1&mode=' + _mode,
        width: 800,
        minLength: 4,
        onSelect: function (value, data) {
            //$data is companyid
                $('#hidSearched CompanyId').val(data);
        }
    });
```

I convert apostrophes to \' which works fine.

Also on the server side - it seems to be working fine because if I search for "O'kee" I get the following response:

```
{ query:'o´kee',suggestions:['O´Keeffe],data:['3355'] }
```

And if I search for "O´kee" (note: another "type" of apostrophe) I get this resonse:

```
{ query:'o´kee',suggestions:['O´Keeffe],data:['3355'] }
```

Actually the very same response which is what I want. But the funny part is that my drop-down list on the input text only shows when I use the ´ sign. Nothing shows when I use the ' (apostrophe) sign.

Comment: Are you using this implementation of the autocomplete feature? https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Comment: Thx Nate, I should consider updating my jquery/autocomplete files. jQuery lib is v1.6.1, jQuery UI v1.8.13 and autocomplete v1.1.3. There will have to be heavy testing of other jQuery features before implementing!